# Java Array Reject Large Values

Tags: java, arrays, average

I am currently creating a simple java application that reads an array of 4 noise values on a graph and then calculates the average and plots this on the graph.

I am aiming to remove 'false alarm' values by rejecting any array readings that are more than twice the average of the other 3 results.

E.g:

```
Array [1] = 50
Array [2] = 48 
Array [3] = 53
Array [4] = 102  < Reject this value as it is more than twice the level of the average of the other 3 results (Average = 100.7)
```

How could this be implemented within an if statement? So that it forgets about the 'false alarm' value? It could be any Array [x] that could be rejected. Thanks.

Comment: Loop through each index, calculate the average for all other indices *except* that one, and check if it matches the predicate.

Comment: `if (Array[3] > (Array[0] + Array[1] + Array[2])/3)` Note array starts with 0th index

Comment: Thanks, but the amount of arrays initialised varies on the constructor therefore I can't set specific numbers within the statement. It just needs to reject any Array [x] which proves to be 2 * (Average of all other arrays).

Comment: Since you want to exclude the highest number in your average I would search for the highest number, calculate the average of the others and then check if this highest number fits in with the average or not. You then could repeat this step until you don't find any "false alarms" anymore.

Answer (score 2):

My answer is very similar to [Clashsoft's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34695602/4452290), but slightly more efficient in the sense that it's O(length) instead of O(length^2).

```
/* Returns the index of the false alarm if exists, otherwise -1 */
public static int falseAlarm(double[] array){
    int length = array.length;
    double total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        total += array[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        double average = (total - array[i])/(length - 1);
        if (array[i] > average * 2)
            return i; // early return if false alarm is found
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot solve this problem with a single `if` statement (at least not in a sane way). However, you can use `for` statements:

```
public static int falseAlarm(double[] values)
{
    final int length = values.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        double average = 0D
        for (int j = 0; j < length; j++)
        {
            if (j != i) average += values[j]
        }
        average /= length - 1

        final double value = values[i]
        if (value > average * 2)
        {
            return i; // i - false alarm index
        }
    }
    return -1; // no false alarm
}
```

The above method returns the index of the value that represents the 'false alarm'.